# Adding Authorization token to header in JavaScript to fetch data from API

Tags: javascript, http-headers, authorization, bearer-token

I am trying to build a frontend interface to communicate with an API service, I am using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am using async function / await fetch to call the API and response.jsom to retrieve the JSON data from the response, now I have to add X-Authorization:Bearer Token '.....' to the header, how can I do that with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Add your token inside the header, here is an example, call this postData function anywhere from your application, you can add it in a common place

Also check
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
this for the detailed explanation

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  let token = "Get your token here, Store it in local storage and read it from local storage is a better method"
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "X-Authorization":Bearer Token '.....' // Here you can add your token
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
```